# Is it possible to write impossible assembly code?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

By saying that i mean lets say we have this

```
xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ...
```

byte stream.

Now, if disassembler goes through EVERY POSSIBLE combination of that stream, will it complain at any point that command is impossible? I want disassembler to provide a LEGIT output for every possible combination, doesn't matter what it does, but I want it to succeed in spitting out instructions no matter what.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, this happens quite often.  Code often contains data as well.  Like inline strings or tables, like the kind generated for a switch statement.  A jump table, containing addresses instead of code.  Disassembler tend to fall over badly on such code.  They can usually figure out that the first table entry is an address but don't know how long the table is.

But that usually just generates mangled assembly code, typical processors don't have that many impossible instructions.  They tend to map just about any byte value to an instruction.  YMMV.

Comment: +1 Probably this is what OP is asking.

Answer (score 3):

Strange question, not sure I'm understanding you correctly, but...

No, not possible. Not every combination of bits corresponds to a valid instruction. Instructions have a predefined format. Anything not conforming to this format will raise an "invalid instruction" hardware exception/trap/interrrupt.

Also if the byte stream is too long, having all possible combinations might take *some* time.

Answer (score 3):

Some processors use fixed-length instructions, and every possible combination of bits that could appear in an instruction has a well-defined meaning.  Some use fixed-length instructions, but certain combinations of bits do not have any defined meaning (the manufacturer does not specify what if anything will happen if an attempt is made to execute such combinations).  In either case, it's fairly easy to determine what code will do if it is ever executed.

On many other processors, the meaning of a sequence of code bytes will depend upon where one starts parsing it.  On the 6502 processor, the byte sequence (starting at address 0xFFC0):

```
A9 00 2C A9 01 85 73 ...
```

would be processed as

```
FFC0:   A9 00    -- LDA #$00
FFC2:   2C A9 01 -- BIT $01A9
FFC5:   85 73    -- STA $73
FFC6:   ...
```

If execution started at address 0xFFC3, however, the sequence would be processed as

```
FFC3:   A9 01    -- LDA #$01
FFC5:   85 73    -- STA $73
FFC6:   ...
```

It's not possible to say with certainty whether the `A9 01` at address 0xFFC3 is an "LDA #$01" instruction, or the operand to a "BIT" instruction.  Indeed, in some real-world 6502 code, the same bytes may get used for both purposes (the only effect of BIT $01A9 instruction will generally be to set some flags, so the $2C opcode effectively serves to skip the next two bytes).

On many processors, there are no uniquely-defined mnemonics for all possible byte codes.  As such, the only way to generate them in assembly language may be to explicitly use a define-byte directive.  On the 6502, for example, an attempt to execute certain byte values including 0x02, 0x12, and 0x22 will stall the processor until the next reset.  Since such behavior isn't useful, there is no defined opcode assigned to them.  Some later derivatives of the 6502 perform more useful operations when executing such opcodes, and assemblers that target those particular derivatives would have mnemonics that could generate them, but otherwise common behavior for a disassembler would either be to disassemble 0x02 as something like "???", or "?02", or assume a generic pseudo-opcode related to its apparent function (e.g. "KIL").

Comment: +1 Good point about where to start parsing.

Comment: BTW, there are some opcodes like 0xA7 which would not have been produced by any 6502 assemblers back in the day, but which can nonetheless be useful.  The processor regards all opcodes of the form `101001xx` as a request to load something from zero page.  If neither `x` is set, the read value gets latched by the Y register.  If the first `x` is set, the X register.  If the second, the accumulator.  As it happens, if both x's are set (opcode 10100111), the value gets latched by both the accumulator and X register.